# Asynchronous method call in CDI

Tags: java, cdi

I am trying to have an asynchronous method call in a CDI bean and get the behavior like @Asynchronous of EJB. For that purpose I am writing an annotation as:

```
@InterceptorBinding
@Target({ METHOD, TYPE })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface SimpleAsync {

}
```

I am handling this annotation with the code:

```
 @AroundInvoke
public Object callAsync(InvocationContext ctx) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("around invoke is called"+ctx.getMethod());
    Runnable runImpl = new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            try{
               ctx.proceed();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
     };

   Thread t = new Thread(runImpl);
   t.start();
   System.out.println("after thread start");
  }
```

Whenever I am calling `ctx.proceed` in the new thread, the `callAsync` method is entering into an infinite loop and the actual method, on which I have put the `@SimpleAsync` annotation is never executed.

Is it required that `ctx.proceed` should be called from the same thread, and if so is there any other way to achieve an asynchronous method call in CDI?

Comment: What you are trying to do seems very dangerous, because you're likely to mess up your contexts by switching threads like that. May I ask what the scope of the bean is that you're applying the annotation to?
I suspect what is happening is that when you first invoke the method, the underlying bean is resolved, the interceptor is applied, then in the new thread it attempts to resolve the bean again but the context is different and doesn't contain the bean so a new one is created, which in turn has a new interceptor and so on.

Comment: thanks.. got your point!! that must be the case. CDI beans are in their default scope only. Now I think, using EJBs are the best way to go.